# Using Travis CI to compile c++ project

Tags: c++, compilation

i'm new at Travis CI and I want to ask you how to exactly use Travis CI to compile OpenGL with a lot .cpp, .h files. If you can hint me how to create correct `.travis.yml` file.

Also I tried to this but i'm getting this error:

```
The command "./configure && make" exited with 127.

/home/travis/build.sh: line 41: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

`.travis.yml` file:

```
language: cpp

compiler:

  - gcc
  - clang
```

Change this to your needs

```
script: ./configure && make
```

Comment: Link to travis please

Comment: did you install all your dependencies first?

Comment: this is the problem that i don't know what dependencies to install

Comment: _`./configure: No such file or directory`_ So is there a `configure` file in the directory you're trying to call it from?

Comment: Can you link to the project? Or at least provide more information about the build system?

Comment: I'm building my project with gcc compiler using CodeBlocks program, but I just got free access to Travis and I want to try to work with that.

Comment: You need to generate a build script that can be used to build the project outside Code Blocks. Otherwise, Travis doesn't know how to handle your source files. If I can suggest one, try using `CMake`. Travis does not compile, Travis observes something else compile and checks its work.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a 'configure' file in the directory where the build starts.  It is possible that you are using autotools, and need to run ./autogen.sh or autoreconf first, which generates the configure file.  It is possible you are integrating travis with github, and your repository has a .gitignore that ignores the configure file (as it should) so that there is no configure file in the repository (only in your build directory on your dev machine.)